# Adb command to get gsm info

Tags: android, adb

I need get GSM info from Adb.
I need GSM network Operator name and other info.
A command for get this info.

```
getprop gsm.network.type
```

this Command not work.

Comment: define "don't work", how do you use it?

Comment: Why is a small apk no option?

Comment: adb shell getprop gsm.network.type

Comment: this is an Adb command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the correct comand to get gsm info is

use

```
adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry
```