# How to get network providers name in Appium through Java?

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

Is there any way to fetch network providers name in Appium through java?
I tried below code to add in my script but I am not sure which class or jar to use for TelephonyManager.

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName(); // alphabetic name of current registered operator
return carrierName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [get carrier information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052265/adb-command-to-get-gsm-info) you can use **ADB**:

```
adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry
```

To run adb via Appium you have to use **[mobile-command API](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/)**:

```
Object result = driver.executeScript(
    "mobile: shell",
    "dumpsys telephony.registry"
);
```

NOTE: as documentation states you have to start Appium server with `--relaxed-security` flag